# Error: No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? Angular 7

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm getting an error when clicking the "test" button to open modal component :

Error: No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
I am using ng-bootstrap 2.0.0 locally and the example working just fine but when upgrading ng-bootstrap to 4.0.0 I am getting the same error as the above. For some reason the Stackblitz produces the same error. In stackblitz, I tried to upgrade ng-bootstrap to 4.0.0 but I am getting error "Can't find package:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap".

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbootstrap-table-enn161?file=package.json

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are passing incorrect value to `modalService.open()`, `currentGridControl` is not a `component`.

Change below line in `map-search-grid.component.ts`

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(this.currentGridControl);
```

to

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MapSearchGridControlComponent);
```

See below working fork -

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbootstrap-table-7je2or?file=app%2Fmap-search-grid.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Error: No component factory found for [object Object].

Based on the error, whatever method or service you're calling is expecting a component type or templateref.